# How can I debug a .exe file if I'm running it from a different folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio Express 2013

I've tried both of the following lines of code to try and grab the location of a an .exe I'm running but I can't seem to get this right. Basically, I wrote an .exe but I need to debug it from another location than the bin\debug folder. Is there another way I should be doing this? Attaching to a running process doesn't seem to work because the code is failing as soon as it starts.

// find the directory this .bat or .exe is currently placed

```
string path_string = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Comment: Add a Thread.Sleep(10000) on your main, then you will have enough time to attach to it, or add a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Erik Visual Studio Express doesn't have that functionality unfortunately, so I found a workaround. Thanks for the tip though, definitely turned the lightbulb on! Hopefully this helps someone else as well

[image: vs2013_express]

Basically, you'll want to edit the .csproj of your file. Does the same thing that you're doing in the Professional version's gui. Add the lines below before the Property Group tag ends and it should help.

[image: possible solution]

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a path to a program to start when debugging in Visual Studio.

Go to the properties of your project, click the Debug tab, and choose "Start external program". Then enter the path to where the exe is located.

[image: Visual Studio Properties Window]

Comment: partial answer - i'm running VS2013 Express so I don't have that functionality. I took your idea and ran with it though - you can add more a few xml lines to the .csproj file to get it to do the same thing. I have a photo of the steps below for anyone who wants the answer

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

to the beginning of your program.  Then when you double click the exe (It must be a debug build), you'll be prompt to attach code to the exe for debugging.

The prompt should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2012:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly newAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("ProcessTarget.exe");
    newAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[1] { new string[0] });
}
```

Both projects are in my solution.  The above is the startup project.  I put a breakpoint in the other (ProcessTarget) and pressed F5.  Execution stopped at the breakpoint.

When you do this, the second .exe (ProcessTarget) behaves like a DLL.  For example, it uses the App.config from the startup project.